# Скрипт PHP выполняется сам почему?

Tags: php, скрипт

Коллеги, добрый день!
Подскажите есть скрипт записи в файл при нажатии на кнопку на php. Проблема в том, что это скрипт выполняется периодически сам. При этом в файл записывается запись типа `die(@md5(Apri1));`. Скрипт выполняется не в определённое время. Бывает несколько дней всё нормально, а потом выполнится. Может это вирусы какие-нибудь. Как можно уйти от этой проблемы.

Comment: Мало информации. Где лежит скрипт? Он доступен для запуска извне? Смотрели записи крон? Пробовали искать по всем файлам die(@md5(Apri1)); ?

Comment: Так может кто-то периодически нажимает на ту самую кнопку?

Comment: Пишите в нём логи и смотрите через пару дней)

Answer (score 3):

Это всего лишь [шум из разных ботнетов](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_background_noise), пытающихся найти уязвимости в веб-сайтах. Такие боты отправляют запросы на разные IP-адреса, и выглядят они примерно вот так:

```
POST /xx.php - body: b"xx=die(@md5(Apri1));"
POST /wuwu11.php - body: b"h=die(@md5(Apri1));"
```

В вашем случае это безопасно, так как аргумент не выполняется, а просто записывается в файл.

Как вариант, можно переименовать скрипт, поместить его в другую папку или не использовать расширение `.php` для страниц сайта (с помощью `mod_rewrite` для Apache, или `rewrite` для nginx). Как правило, большинство ботов делают запросы, оканчивающиеся на `.php`, и лучше избегать таких файлов по крайней мере в корне сайта, а лучше всего отвечать на любые такие запросы ошибкой 403.